# Replace the first 3 white space coming with a character and ignore other white spaces in a text line with python

Tags: python, regex

I have this line text:

```
09-15-16 05:23:44 A:VCOM     09064 Port 4 Device 10400 Remote 1 10401 Link Up RP2009
```

the output should be like this:

```
09-15-16|05:23:44|A:VCOM|09064|Port 4 Device 10400 Remote 1 10401 Link Up RP2009
```

It should just replace the first 4 white spaces with | and ignore the rest.

This is the simple code I used :

```
import re
text = "09-15-16 05:23:44 A:VCOM     09064 Port 4 Device 10400 Remote 1 10401 Link Up RP2009"
i = 0
while i< 3:
    text = re.sub(' ', '|', text)
    text = re.sub('     ', '|', text)
    i +=1

print text
```

I got this output :

```
09-15-16|05:23:44|A:VCOM|||||09064|Port|4|Device|10400|Remote|1|10401|Link|Up|RP2009
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

print re.sub(r' +','|',text,4)
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex for that. Just use `str.split` with a `maxsplit`:

```
>>> s = '09-15-16 05:23:44 A:VCOM     09064 Port 4 Device 10400 Remote 1 10401 Link Up RP2009'
>>> *first, last = s.split(maxsplit=4)
>>> '|'.join(first) + '|' + last
'09-15-16|05:23:44|A:VCOM|09064|Port 4 Device 10400 Remote 1 10401 Link Up RP2009'
```

For Python 2:

```
>>> s = '09-15-16 05:23:44 A:VCOM     09064 Port 4 Device 10400 Remote 1 10401 Link Up RP2009'
>>> items = s.split(None, 4)
>>> '|'.join(items[:-1]) + '|' + items[-1]
'09-15-16|05:23:44|A:VCOM|09064|Port 4 Device 10400 Remote 1 10401 Link Up RP2009'
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast response, I got an error about split function
    first, last = text.split(maxsplit=4)
TypeError: split() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: @Ahmed - See the edit for a Python 2-friendly version.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like this:

```
text = "09-15-16 05:23:44 A:VCOM     09064 Port 4 Device 10400 Remote 1 10401 Link Up RP2009"
text = text.replace(" ", "|", 3)
text = text.replace("    ", "")
text = text.replace(" ", "|", 1)
```

Comment: output: 09-15-16|05:23:44|A:VCOM|09064|Port 4 Device 10400 Remote 1 10401 Link Up RP2009

Comment: simply these two lines: text = text.replace("    ", "")
text = text.replace(" ", "|", 4)

   You give very easy code, I like it.

Comment: @Ahmed Even better, you got it!

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

*

```
str = '09-15-16 05:23:44 A:VCOM     09064 Port 4 Device 10400 Remote 1 10401 Link Up RP2009'
idx=0
newStr =''
for token in str.split(' '):
    if(token!=''):
        if(idx <4):
            newStr=newStr + token+'|'
            idx+=1
        else:
            newStr = newStr + token+' '
            idx+=1

print(newStr)
```

desired output

```
09-15-16|05:23:44|A:VCOM|09064|Port 4 Device 10400 Remote 1 10401 Link Up RP2
```